# ERROR running force:source:pull: Cannot retrieve translation for object:null

Tags: salesforcedx, translation

Currently new to SF & came around this error (**Cannot retrieve translation for object:null**) when trying to pull changes from my Scratch Org.
Any suggestions on how to fix this issue as im not finding anything of help elsewhere.